# How to create a simple map for simulation in stdr simulator?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to carry out a simple simulation in stdr simulator for which I'll be needing a simple map with four boundaries i.e. a square room. How do I create a map for this purpose?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/335062/how-to-create-a-simple-map-for-simulation-in-stdr-simulator?/) by [electrophod](https://answers.ros.org/users/43169/electrophod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 277 on 2019-10-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It has been a while since I have used `stdr_simulator` but map in only a png file.
So you can create such map manually in a drawing software like [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/).

Then, add a metadata file with the same name but with the `.yaml` extension. This file will contain the following elements:

```
image: frieburg.png
resolution: 0.05
origin: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
occupied_thresh: 0.6
free_thresh: 0.3
negate: 0
```

The above example comes from the [stdr_ressouces](https://github.com/stdr-simulator-ros-pkg/stdr_simulator/tree/indigo-devel/stdr_resources/maps) package.

---

Originally posted by [rreignier](https://answers.ros.org/users/21983/rreignier/) with karma: 544 on 2019-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1